# Mongodb throwing an error when I run the query to record last position from oplog

Tags: mongodb, query, errors

I am getting an error when I run the query in the secondary member to record the last position from the oplog.

below is the query.

```
db.oplog.rs.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).next().ts
```

and the error I am getting is

```
2019-05-20T12:49:26.566+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1558355938, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotMasterNoSlaveOk",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1558356558, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:725:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:117:28
DBQuery.prototype.next@src/mongo/shell/query.js:307:5
@(shell):1:1
```

can someone help me to get out of this issue?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990428/3432487